# How can I make the dotnet command the second command in docker?

Tags: docker

This is my `CMD` directive in my Dockerfile:

```
CMD [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "dotnet /Project/Api.dll" ]
```

And when I use `docker exec -it` to get an interactive bash into my container, I see that `dotnet` PID is 1.

```
ps -ef
```

This means that I can't kill it and rerun it. `kill -9 1` does not work.

How can I make it not the entry process? How can I run something before it, so that I can kill it inside the container?

Comment: The container effectively _is_ the process.  You don't `docker exec` into a container to kill its main process; you just `docker stop` the container.

Answer (score 0):

```
CMD [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "dotnet /Project/Api.dll" ]
```

Given command works well but as your requirement is to run this later right?

You can always write your custom shell logic/processing in a separate script and run it instead of running the above command.

This will smartly assign different pid to your dotnet process.

```
#!/bin/bash

#some logic
dotnet /Project/Api.dll
```

And you will run your script like

```
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

This will solve your issue to a greater extent.

Lastly to end/kill your dotnet process gracefully and not use kill command which is ultra invasive.
you can use a combination of putting your dotnet app in the `background` and then combining it with Linux command `term` command which gives you a great exit/error hook to work upon.

Additionally there is this great thread about the pid1 scenario you are referring to:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457649/unable-to-kill-process-with-pid-1-in-docker-container

Hope this helps.