# Docker not stopping with Ctrl+C

Tags: docker

Can you help me understand why I can't stop my Docker container?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.4-alpine3.15

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev python3-dev libffi-dev \
    && pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "docker_init.sh"]
```

The problem began when I replaced CMD with ENTRYPOINT cause I needed to run some other stuff. This is the `docker_init.sh` file:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py init_admin
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Now, I can't stop the Docker container with Ctrl+C. I need to close the terminal, stop Docker and restart it (I'm using Linux).

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+D?

Comment: @Anton Yes. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: check this out and let me know if this works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75910305/how-can-i-make-the-dotnet-command-the-second-command-in-docker/75910448#75910448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this setup, the main container process is no longer your Python script but the shell-script wrapper.  You can see this if you `docker exec running-container-name ps`: process ID 1 will be `sh` here.

You can fix this by using the shell [`exec`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_20) builtin to replace the shell with the main command.  The setup will run under the shell but then the last command will switch over to the Django application as the main process.

```bash
exec python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

A more general form of this is an *entrypoint wrapper script*.  If you make that last line be `exec "$@"` then the shell will replace itself with whatever was passed as its command-line arguments.  When Docker runs a container, if it has both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, the command is passed as arguments to the entrypoint, and it's a little easier to override the command part (`docker run --rm -it your-container bash` for example).  This can give you a setup where you have an interactive debugging shell in a temporary container, but all of the entrypoint setup steps have been done.

So for this, keep the entrypoint as-is, except you don't put a specific command at the end:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py init_admin
exec "$@"
```

In the Dockerfile, keep the `CMD` you had originally, and also add the `ENTRYPOINT`

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker_init.sh"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```